# How do I perform multiplication within a group in Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an Orders model which contains a beverage ID and both quantity and unit price, which are multiplied together to give a total order value.

In another part of my app, I need to group orders by the beverage ID and then sum all of the order values to give the total stock value on hand.

When I need to calculate the total quantity on hand, I do it like this in the controller:

```
@delivery_total = Order.group(:beverage_id).sum(:quantity, :conditions => {:orderable_type => 'Delivery'})
```

(I filter by orderable_type as there are also returns)

So I thought, when I need to calculate the total order value, it would be the following:

```
@delivery_value = Order.group(:beverage_id).sum((:quantity * :price), :conditions => {:orderable_type => 'Delivery'})
```

But that doesn't work, giving the error

> undefined method `*' for :quantity:Symbol

I'm afraid I'm still learning here... Can anyone advise the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of `sum` should be a String, like this:

```
@delivery_total = Order.group(:beverage_id).sum("quantity * price", :conditions => {:orderable_type => 'Delivery'})
```

Comment: Thanks - much cleaner. But throws an error about not finding the column: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: total_price: SELECT SUM(total_price) AS sum_total_price, beverage_id AS beverage_id FROM "orders"  WHERE "orders"."orderable_type" = 'Delivery' GROUP BY beverage_id

Comment: @Nick Sorry, my previous answer was wrong. I mistook ActiveRecord::Calculations#sum for something inside Enumerable. Would you try the new answer?